# ruby pack and hex values

Tags: ruby, decoding, pack, hex, unpack

A nibble is four bits. That means there are 16 (2^4) possible values. That means a nibble corresponds to a single hex digit, since hex is base 16. A byte is 2^8, which therefore can be represented by 2 hex digits, and consequently 2 nibbles.

So here below I have a 1 byte character:

'A'

That character is 2^8:

```
 'A'.unpack('B*')
 => ["01000001"]
```

That means it should be represented by two hex digits:

```
 01000001 == 41
```

According to the Ruby documentation, for the Array method pack, when aTemplateString (the parameter) is equal to 'H', then it will return a hex string. But this is what I get back:

```
['A'].pack('H')
 => "\xA0"
```

My first point is that's not the hex value it should return. It should have returned the hex value of 41. The second point is the concept of nibble, as I explained above, means for 1 byte, it should return two nibbles. But above it inserts a 0, because it thinks the input only has 1 nibble, even though 'A' is one byte and has two nibbles. So clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you looking for `'A'.unpack('H*') #=> ["41"]`?

Comment: @Stefan you have high rep,so could you add tag `pack` and `unpack` too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
'A'.unpack('H*') #=> ["41"]
```

[`pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) does the opposite:

```
['41'].pack('H*') #=> "A"
```

Comment: These are 2 methods from String class I still not being able to understand :(

Comment: @Stefan I would like to know where this "\xA0" comes from. A0 is not the hex value of 'A'. What is it? And why is it inserting a 0 when 'A' is two nibbles?

Comment: `['A'].pack('H')` creates a character with hex code `0xA0` which is outside the ASCII range, just like `['41'].pack('H*')` creates a character with hex code `0x41` which is represented as `A`.

Comment: Yes, I see that it creates the hex A0. But why does it create A0 and not 41? The hex of 'A' is 41. Where does A0 come from?

Comment: It's equivalent to `0x41.chr` vs. `0xA0.chr`

Comment: Yes, I know that 0x and \x are both symbols that indicate hexadecimal values will appear after. But my question is still the same. The capital letter A in hex is 41, not A0. The parameter 'H' according to the documentation says it converts the input value to hex. 'A' converted to hex is not A0. So why does A0 even have any relevance here?

Comment: After I look over this again, I think I see what is going on here. pack is trying to take a binary and convert it into hex. But 'A' is not a binary so it doesn't know what to do with it - so it just creates a hex A with 0 as padding.

Comment: It does convert the input value to hex: `"41"` is converted to `0x41` and `"A"` in converted to `0xA0`. `0` is appended because `H` means high nibble first. Just like `["4"].pack("H")` is converted to `0x40`, the character `@`.

Comment: I understand it now. Basically H tells pack to treat the contents of the array as hex values. It is treating 'A' as a hex value not the ascii 'A'. Hence, it just outputs the A (4 bits) and appends a 0, since its only a 4 bit single nibble. And since H means high nibble first, A proceeds the 0 when creating the multi nibble.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky. ["1"].pack("H") => "\x10" and ["16"].pack("H") => "\x10". I spent long long time to understand this.